# How to use multiple fonts in a single line Using C# iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext, itext7

How to use multiple fonts in a single line Using **PdfContentByte**

For Example:

```
pcb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT, "Some normal font" + " Bold Font" + " Some normal font",iXCoordinate, iYCoordinate, 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a different version of the `ShowTextAligned()` method to achieve this.

```
ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(pcb, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, phrase, iXCoordinate, iYCoordinate, 0);
```

The `phrase` parameter is of type `Phrase` and it can be composed of `Chunk` objects with different fonts.